# Android studio auto import for flutter_gen

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have `AppLocalizations` class the generated by `flutter_gen`
Android studio cannot automatically import it, I tried to remove the `.dart_tool/flutter_gen` from exclude list, but still automatically import not working